# Mysql Query to select all the tables with same column name

Tags: mysql

To be specific I am using MySql.I have many tables in my database, like employee, student, employer etc etc. There are more than 20 such tables. And in each table, I have a column called 'username' and 'age'. Now I want a query that will  give me the all the ages when i give a particular username='alex'.

Comment: Looks like poor design to me.

Comment: do you want to retrieve data from three tables which are conencted?

Comment: I dont have experience with this kind of problem, but this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html looks like an answer to your problem

Answer (score 1):

You probably should have a single table (say, `Users`) which has a *column* indicating what type of person that user is (employee, student, employer, etc.).  However, if you *must* query across multiple tables of this sort, use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html):

```
SELECT age FROM employee WHERE username = 'alex' UNION ALL
SELECT age FROM student  WHERE username = 'alex' UNION ALL
SELECT age FROM employer WHERE username = 'alex' -- etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like poor design of the database and if you can change the database structure, that's probably the way to go. Otherwise, you could try this:

```
(SELECT username, age
 FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT username, age
 FROM table2)
UNION
(SELECT username, age
 FROM table3)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Query to get and tablenames having a particular column

```
select table_name from information_schema.columns 
where table_name in (
select table_name from information_schema.tables
where table_schema='databaseName'
) and 
column_name='username';
```

from the above query you will be all tablenames which have the field username then i PHP you can build query to get values from all the tables;